# Handle NDJSON Stream Promises in Stache Can.js

Tags: javascript, mustache, canjs, canjs-view, asynchronous-javascript

I have this streaming API endpoint:

https://step3-ndjson-stream-api-demo.glitch.me/

I try to render with [can.js NDJSON stream](https://canjs.com/doc/can-ndjson-stream.html) and following the example got some success output to console.log but only the first object.

Here's my app.js (truncated):

```
const AppViewModel = DefineMap.extend("AppViewModel", {
  // misc. properties, then
  get streamFunct(){
      return fetch(
        'https://step3-ndjson-stream-api-demo.glitch.me/'
      ).then(function(response){
        return ndjsonStream( response.body );
      }).then( ( streamData ) => {

        const reader = streamData.getReader();
        let read;

        reader.read().then( read = ( result ) => {
            if ( result.done ) {
                return;
            }
            console.log( result.value );
            streamData.getReader().read().then( read );
        } );
    } );
  }
});
```

And here's a snippet from my index.stache:

```
<p>Stream Data: <strong>{{streamFunct}}</strong></p>
```

And my console developer view (note the successful first call):

[image: console view]

I think I have to handle the promise object in the index.stache but not sure... Thank you for looking.

**UPDATE**

Finally I'm able to get the streamed data:

```
  get streamFunct(){
  return fetch(
    'https://step3-ndjson-stream-api-demo.glitch.me/'
  ).then(function(response){
    return ndjsonStream( response.body );
  }).then( ( streamData ) => {

    //retain access to the reader so that you can cancel it
    const reader = streamData.getReader();
    const listResult = document.querySelector('.displayResult ul')
    let read;

    reader.read().then( read = ( result ) => {
        if ( result.done ) {
            console.log('Failed to find match');
            return;
        }
        const chunk = result.value;
        let listItem = document.createElement('li');
        listItem.textContent = chunk.user;
        listResult.appendChild(listItem);
        
        return reader.read().then(read);
    } ).catch ((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
} );
```

}

And modify my index.stache:

```
<p>Stream Data:</p>
<div class="displayResult">
<ul>

</ul>
</div>
```

But I still got errors/warnings:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]:
> Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
>
> [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are
> deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled
> will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
>
> Failed promise: TypeError: response.getReader is not a function

Does anyone know how to clear them?

Comment: You are getting these errors in chrome or in node? `[DEP0018]` seems like a node error.

Comment: Also, for displaying the results of the stream, have you looked at using: https://canjs.com/doc/can-connect-ndjson.html ?

Comment: Hey @Ardhi, I think you've likely discovered a bug with that error message. If you wouldn't mind filing an issue at https://github.com/donejs/done-ssr i'll take a look.

Comment: @ardhi I've discovered this bug and am in the process of fixing it.

Comment: @MatthewPhillips thank you, I haven't had time to do the suggestion, I'll try to take a look later..

Comment: Just to let everyone knows, although haven't tried it again with can-js, I managed to make `ndjsonStream` works with react.